# Distinguish clicked and unclicked divs React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, weather-api

I have a simple task to do in react, but this step has become a painful one for me.

I have fetched an api and stored temperatures of two different cities in two different variables using state.

The task is as follows:

```js
if(clickedTemp>notClickedTemp){
    setState({
        score: this.state.score+=1
    })
}
```

This is the pseudo code, but I cannot write a real one that works :(

The cities fetch from the api randomly using their ids, please help if you can

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more on your current problem and share what you have done so far?

Comment: Please post full component and what's the goal exactly.

Comment: 1. Your setState has an error in the key socre 2. Don't mutate state directly. setState({ ...this.state, score: this.state.score+1 })

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand quite right what you're after. To me it looks like you want to compare two variables? And then make a ++ to the react state?

If so, it should be something like this.

```
if (var1 > var2) {
    let actualScore = this.state.score;
    actualScore++;
    this.setState({
        score: actualScore
    })
})
```

Be careful though, because if the var1 and var2 are not numbers, it won't work as expected.

Comment: The thing is that we are comparing the value which was clicked to another value,and that makes it confusing for me, not just two values a and be

Answer (score 0):

I would switch to React Hooks for this. It's as simple as

```
//... inside a function component
const [clickedTemp, setClickedTemp] = React.useState()
const [notClickedTemp, setNotClickedTemp] = React.useState()
const [score, setScore] = React.useState(0)

React.useEffect(() => {
    if (clickedTemp > notClickedTemp) {
        setScore(score + 1)
    }
}, [clickedTemp, notClickedTemp])
```

This way, every time you fetch your data, you can update it using `setClickedTemp(fetchedData)` and `setNotClickedTemp(fetchedData)`, and the `useEffect` hook will automatically detect the change, make the comparison, and update the score.

More info on React Hooks, useState, and useEffect [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html).

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that the OP was not able to use hooks properly?